# Is it a bad idea to put an array of objects in its class as a data member?

Tags: java, c++, oop

I mean, I have a class A, and I have an array of A as a static data member of class A. Is is a bad practice?

Comment: Maybe, but it's sometimes valid. There isn't enough information here to say...

Comment: Pick a language, Java and C++ are very different.

Comment: @Collin C++ has one copy for static data

Comment: @billz Yeah, missed the static the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, it will result in a memory leak ... unless you do something messy and complicated with finalizers or `Reference` objects.

If your aim is to keep a collection of all instance ever created, you need to *be very careful!!*  A collection of all instances created is going to leak memory, no matter how you implement it.  (This is only really acceptable if the leak is either bounded, or small enough to not matter in the context of the entire application.)

If your aim is to keep a cache of existing instances to (for instance) to offset some particularly large object creation / initialization overheads, then you should use a `WeakHashMap` or an existing 3rd-party cache class rather than trying to implement it from scratch using arrays.

Comment: Good idea?  Probably not.  Memory leak?  I can't imagine how it can be classified as such.  I mean, you're not *losing* these references, they're still available to be removed from the array, they just have the tendency to go stale if not maintained.

Comment: @Ed S.  In Java, a memory leak is where objects that are never going to be used again remain reachable (and are not garbage collected) for far too long.  So, in this case, unless something is actively removing objects from the array it is a memory leak.  And if you are keeping a collection of all objects created, then obviously you cannot remove objects ... 'cos that would defeat the purpose of the collection.

Comment: It's not really a "leak", is it, in the sense of "definitely lost" memory. It's more like a "pin cushion" or something like that.

Comment: @Stephen C: Well, I'm not so sure that is a widely accepted definition, but I know and I agree with what you're saying.  Whatever the semantics are, if you are stuck with a bunch of objects that aren't being freed then you may as well call it a leak because you're running out of memory.  However, it's not a situation that most (I) would call a leak because *the objects are still reachable*, you've chosen to keep references around for whatever reason.

Comment: I can conjure up a more apt example of a leak in a managed languages using static events in C#.  In that case you may end up with stale references which can no longer be cleaned up because the subscriber went out of scope.

Comment: @EdS. It is widely accepted in the Java world.  Trust me.  And the reason we use this definition is because the other (i.e. C / C++) kind of memory leak is **impossible** in pure Java.  But this is hair-splitting.  The problem is real whether you call it a memory leak, or "indoor cricket with a cat".